# Where is the coordinate stored in a typical matrix for graphics?

Tags: matrix, graphics

I'm just now learning about how computer graphics work with matrices and while it's starting to all make sense, I still don't understand where exactly a point is stored in a matrix--or is each point (3D) stored in a vector by itself?

Would a vertex look something like

```
[6 8 3 x]
[5 5 2 y]
[4 9 0 z]
[1 7 8 7]
```

or

```
[x]
[y]
[z]
```

?

Or is a coordinate stored in different areas of a 4x4 matrix depending on how the implementer sets it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points are usually stored in a vector. The reason that a point has 4 components in the implementation while we have only three coordinates is that the last component called usually as w distinguishes points from vectors. Usually vectors have w=0 and points have w=1; note that if you subtract two points you get a vector. p0=(x0,y0,z0,1)-P1(x1,y1,z1,1)=V(v0,v1,v2,0). Matrices however are used to trnasform vertices. They have 4*4 dimensions for two reasons one is they have to have the same dimension with points as they are multiplied in points. The other reason is that a 4*4 matrix can provide translations as well. I strongly suggest you to take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

It describes the whole process of working with matrices, points, and how they work with each other to provide a meaningful final render.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I figured if a point was stored in a vector representation it would have to have four values for valid multiplication by a 4 x 4 matrix, just didn't know how exactly it would be shown.

Comment: And the w-value makes sense for the operations.